# When connecting multiple differential pairs in a D38999 connector, is it common practice to have a ground pin for each differential pair?

Tags: wiring

I have a remote interface unit that has multiple differential pairs going to a from it. Some units that are connected have multiple pairs coming to and from. Should everyone one of the differential pairs actually have a dedicated pin for ground?

Keep in mind, the RS485 reference is just referencing the voltage levels, these are not being used for serial communication.

Comment: It's common-practise to shield a differential pair and that would of course require the presence of a ground pin.

Comment: Are you using the D38999 connector because your communication is "mission critical"? If so, I would follow the specifications regardless of whether it appears you can get away with something less.

Comment: The reference to a D38999 does come with a "mission critical" stamp but I'm the individual designing the spec for the system in question. I understand the need for ground pins but where i'm having trouble is only 1 unit is requesting a dedicated ground pin for each differential (there are 8). I've seen it be common practice to just tie the shield (it's a shielded twisted pair) to the back shell and call it a day.

Comment: For the units that specify a separate ground for each differential pair, you should use a separate ground since who knows how they're connected up on the other end.  It's common with 39999s to have the backshell connected to the chassis ground and have a separate pin for signal ground.  It's also common to just throw several COTS components in a box and wire them up to the same connector.  For units that only specify a single ground for multiple pairs, then you should be fine with just the one signal ground in addition to whatever shielding you think proper.

Comment: VIR, Thank you for the feedback. This is more along the lines of what I was expecting. I appreciate the help.